# Counter example to regular region (infinite spiral?)

Tags: real-analysis

The definition of a regular region (in "A First Course in Real Analysis" by Morray and Protter) is:

> A region $D$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is said to be regular if and only if (i) $D$ is bounded, (ii) $\partial D$ consists of a finite number of piecewise smooth simple closed curves (this means that we have smooth arcs which are joined at corners, a corner being a point where the two tangent line make a positive angle), and (iii) at each point $P$ of $\partial D$ a Cartesian coordinate system can be constructed with $P$ as origin with the following properties: for sufficiently small $a$ and $b$ a rectangle
> $$
> R=\{(x_1,x_2):-a\leq x_1\leq a,-b\leq x_2\leq b\}
> $$
> can be found so that the part of $\partial D$ in $R$ has the form $x_2=f(x_1)$ for $x_1$ on $[-a,a]$ and with range on $[-b,b]$, where $f$ is a piecewise smooth function.

They proceed to give examples of regions that are not regular. See picture:

[image]

Clearly the region with an infinite number of holes doesn't consist of a **finite** number of smooth curves. The infinite spiral would fail property (iii). Note that the infinite spiral is not compact. I am wondering if such a compact example exists.

Question: Is there an example of a (piecewise) smooth (simple closed) curve which maps bounded interval, say $[a,b]$, to the plane, that fails to satisfy property (iii)?

I'm hinging towards no: if our curve $\gamma$ has non-vanishing differential, then I believe we can show that it is locally given by a graph (cf. Lee Prop. 5.16), though I don't know how to show that at the boundary of the curve, which is precisely the tricky part, as the lack of a boundary is what makes the infinite spiral a counter example. I'm also not sure what would happen at the points where the derivative vanishes, especially if we have an accumulation point where the derivative vanishes.

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of a smooth curve?  Must the domain of a smooth curve be bounded?  If so, that is an unusual definition...

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am not sure, but it's also not that important. I will modify my question to just be what I'm really asking, i.e., whether there exists a counter-example from a curve starting from a bounded interval.